# Print filename only with Robocopy

Tags: batch-file, output, robocopy

I'm copying files with Robocopy but path+filename is too long and the output gets too crowded. I would like to display filename only (without path).

My command is:

```
ROBOCOPY /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /nc /ns %path% %local% %filename%
```

and outputs:

```
100%       \\storage\releases\prog\ver\file.exe
```

I would like to output:

```
100%       file.exe
```

I've seen the `/FP` flag but I actually want the opposite of that.

```
/FP : Include Full Pathname of files in the output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indicated command does not return the indicated output. You are explicitly using `/nfl` that will remove the file list.

But, without `/nfl` but keeping `/ndl` we get the indicated behaviour: If we don't include the directory list, file names will include the full path.

To get the required behaviour, remove the `/ndl`. As this will include in the output the folder being processed, if you dont want it, filter the `robocopy` output to discard any line containing a backslash

```dos
robocopy %path% %local% %filename% /NJH /NJS /nc /ns | find /v "\"
```